# For which locally ringed spaces is the structure sheaf given by LRS morphisms to the real line?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, sheaf-theory, manifolds, locally-ringed-spaces

Let $\mathsf{LRS}_{\mathbb R}$ denote the category of locally $\mathbb R$-ringed spaces.

Given a locally ringed space $(X,\mathcal O_X)$, write $C_{(X,\mathcal O_X)}^p$ for the hom-sheaf on $X$ of LRS morphisms $(X,\mathcal O_X)\to (\mathbb R,C_\mathbb{R}^p)$. This assignment defines an endofunctor $$\mathsf{LRS}_{\mathbb R}\overset{C^p}{\longrightarrow}\mathsf{LRS}_{\mathbb R}.$$

Taking a local section $(U,\mathcal O_X|_U)\overset{(t,\psi)}{\longrightarrow}(\mathbb R,C^\infty_\mathbb R)$ of $C^p_{(X,\mathcal O_X)}(U)$ to $\psi_{\mathbb R}(1_\mathbb R)$ defines (by Yoneda) a natural transformation $$c^p:C^p\Rightarrow 1_{\mathsf{LRS}_\mathbb R}.$$

The component of $c^p$ at a $C^p$ premanifold with corners is an isomorphism. This follows from naturality coupled with the fact this holds for sectors in Euclidean space (usually almost by definition).

**Question.** What other kinds of locally ringed spaces have this property?